# Investigate an unwanted shutdown over the weekend

Tags: fedora, logs, reboot, crash

This morning my machine running Fedora 22 was in a state of shutdown showing, IIRC, something like the following, in fullscreen white on black terminal:

```
[Rebooting] ...
System halted.
```

After holding the power button and rebooting I am looking to determine what caused this unwanted reboot. Looking at some logs I know that it was up until at least Sunday 14:00. Is there more information available somewhere in the system? Which process initiated shutdown? Was it a kernel panic, a script, which user, etc?

I don't know of any hardware problem or automatic update procedures. It's a few years old desktop computer that also runs a few cron jobs. It was recently upgraded to a clean Fedora 22 and had been running fine so far.

Using `sudo journalctl -b -1`, I can see systemd intiating shutdown around 17:36, followed by the shutdown sequence precisely 5 minutes later.

There is also the NetworkManager checking connectivity and failing repeatedly around the same time. Here is an extract of the log around that time:

```
Dec 20 17:20:49 <myhostname> NetworkManager[844]: <info>  connectivity: check for uri 'http://fedoraproject.org/static/hotspot.txt' failed with 'Impossible de se connecter : Le réseau n'est pas accessible'
Dec 20 17:25:49 <myhostname> NetworkManager[844]: <info>  connectivity: check for uri 'http://fedoraproject.org/static/hotspot.txt' failed with 'Impossible de se connecter : Le réseau n'est pas accessible'
Dec 20 17:30:49 <myhostname> NetworkManager[844]: <info>  connectivity: check for uri 'http://fedoraproject.org/static/hotspot.txt' failed with 'Impossible de se connecter : Le réseau n'est pas accessible'
Dec 20 17:35:49 <myhostname> NetworkManager[844]: <info>  connectivity: check for uri 'http://fedoraproject.org/static/hotspot.txt' failed with 'Impossible de se connecter : Le réseau n'est pas accessible'
Dec 20 17:36:53 <myhostname> systemd-shutdownd[16731]: Creating /run/nologin, blocking further logins...
Dec 20 17:40:49 <myhostname> NetworkManager[844]: <info>  connectivity: check for uri 'http://fedoraproject.org/static/hotspot.txt' failed with 'Impossible de se connecter : Le réseau n'est pas accessible'
Dec 20 17:41:53 <myhostname> systemd[1]: Stopping Manage Sound Card State (restore and store)...
Dec 20 17:41:53 <myhostname> systemd[1]: Stopping LVM2 PV scan on device 8:2...
Dec 20 17:41:53 <myhostname> systemd[1]: Stopping Restore /run/initramfs on shutdown...
Dec 20 17:41:53 <myhostname> systemd[1]: Stopped Session c1 of user gdm.
... etc (shutdown)
```

Here is the output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub to ESI Port (rev 13)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 13)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 13)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev 13)
00:10.0 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 Physical and Link Layer Registers Port 0 (rev 13)
00:10.1 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 Routing and Protocol Layer Registers Port 0 (rev 13)
00:11.0 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500 Physical and Link Layer Registers Port 1 (rev 13)
00:11.1 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500 Routing & Protocol Layer Register Port 1 (rev 13)
00:14.0 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub System Management Registers (rev 13)
00:14.1 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub GPIO and Scratch Pad Registers (rev 13)
00:14.2 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub Control Status and RAS Registers (rev 13)
00:15.0 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 Trusted Execution Technology Registers (rev 13)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 1
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 6
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 90)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JIR (ICH10R) LPC Interface Controller
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode]
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
0f:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108GL [Quadro 600] (rev a1)
0f:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
37:05.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): LSI Corporation FW322/323 [TrueFire] 1394a Controller (rev 70)
3f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-Core Registers (rev 05)
3f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
3f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
3f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
3f:03.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller (rev 05)
3f:03.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder (rev 05)
3f:03.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers (rev 05)
3f:04.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Control Registers (rev 05)
3f:04.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address Registers (rev 05)
3f:04.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Rank Registers (rev 05)
3f:04.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control Registers (rev 05)
3f:05.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Control Registers (rev 05)
3f:05.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address Registers (rev 05)
3f:05.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Rank Registers (rev 05)
3f:05.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control Registers (rev 05)
3f:06.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Control Registers (rev 05)
3f:06.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Address Registers (rev 05)
3f:06.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Rank Registers (rev 05)
3f:06.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Thermal Control Registers (rev 05)
```

Comment: I'd start by reading the end of the journal from that boot...

Comment: Any logs at all, any hardware you know it is flaky (wifi?), any automatic update procedures, how old is the hardware, what does your machine do?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I added some info in the last paragraph.

Comment: you have systemd so you can see the logs until the reboot with `sudo journalctl  -b -1`.

Comment: @meuh Thanks. I've looked at the logs and added information to my question.

Comment: would you please post your output of `lspci`? Have you configure any watchdog?

Comment: Sure @RuiFRibeiro. I've added it. No watchdog that I'm aware of.

Comment: If you want an answer, delete yours, and add the explanation to your question and explain that the question has changed. Furthermore, you can reproduce this easily I guess. You can shutdown the machine in a terminal, even as the same user, and monitor several logs. A 50 point bounty may help attrack attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it turns out a colleague accidentally ran a delayed shutdown command in the wrong terminal. I'm accepting this answer but it would still be interesting if there had been a way to figure it out from the system.